# Ubuntu partition is not starting, it is stuck in the boot menu

Tags: boot

I have dual boot system
Whenever I start the Ubuntu partition it gets stuck in the booting only. You can check the image below.
[image]

Comment: Can you open a virtual console (Ctrl + Alt + F3, for example) and log in?

Comment: It is stuck in booting only.